# Floyd Warshall algorithm with adjacency matrix

Tags: julia

I'm trying to implement the floyd warshall algorithm but it won't work correctly.

What I want is the shortest path distances from one vertex to another written in a matrix d and the predecessors in a matrix pred. The input is an adjacency matrix which contains all of the edge weights.

```
function FloWa(C)

N = size(C)
n = min(C[1],C[2])

pred = -1*ones(C[1],C[2])
d = C

for k in 1:n
    for i in 1:n
        for j in 1:n
            if d[i,j] > d[i,k] + d[k,j]
                if pred[i,k] == -1
                    pred[i,j] = k
                else
                    pred[i,j] = pred[k,j]
                end
                d[i,j] = d[i,k] + d[k,j]
            end
            if i == j && d[i,i] < 0
                    println("negative Dicycle")
            end
        end
    end
end
return d, pred
end
```

When i am running my code with the matrix

```
A = [0 2 1 4 5 1; 1 0 4 2 3 4; 2 1 0 1 2 4; 3 5 2 0 3 3; 2 4 3 4 0 1; 3 4 7 3 1 0]
```

i don't get the right results.

For d i get the same matrix as A and pred is printed as an Array{Float64}(0,1).

Answer (score 1):

I have not checked the implementation of the algorithm, but you seem to initialize `pred` and `d` incorrectly. Here is a way to do it that is I assume you indented:

```
n = size(C, 1) # get number of rows in C
@assert n == size(C, 2) # make sure that C is square or throw an error
pred = fill(-1, size(C)) # fill pred with -1 and make it have the same size as C
d = copy(C) # d is a copy of C
```